# Trying to use term document matrix as input to orange 3

Tags: orange, topic-model, lda

I have a CSV file that has tokens as columns and documents as rows, where the rest of the cells are ints that represent term frequency. I'm trying to use this as input into Orange 3, but Orange 3 doesn't seem to be prepared to handle a term-document matrix as an input. Is there something that I'm missing?

I'm trying to perform topic modeling (hierarchichal dirichlet processing and latent dirichlet allocation, to be specific).